# Event listener onkeydown issue Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a hangman game, but my event listener doesn't seem as though it's working? When I press a key, there's no response from the webpage.

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    // If the game is finished, one keystroke will reset the game
    if (hasFinished) {
        resetGame();
        hasFinished = false;
        console.log("eventListenerWorking16");
    } else {
        // Make sure A-Z was actually pressed
        if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keycode <= 90) {
            makeGuess(event.key.toLowerCase());
            updateDisplay();
            checkWin();
            checkLoss();
            console.log("eventListenerWorking16");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh great ..   One typo can takes hrs to resolve

One typo in this line

```
if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keycode <= 90) {
```

It has to be `event.keyCode`  Caps not small

Comment: Well, i have to say definitely the problem was not in the event listener :)
Anyway if event is not fired at all, it's strange this was cause of that.

Comment: I was thinking that too.. but it worked, and javascript will be javascript

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the event should fire correctly.
I think to make a better debug you should place a console.log right after the anonymous function call (see code below).
This way it will be possible to understand if there is something wrong after (that concerns the logic applied later).

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    console.log("keydown event fired");
    // If the game is finished, one keystroke will reset the game
    if (hasFinished) {
        resetGame();
        hasFinished = false;
        console.log("eventListenerWorking16 hasFinished");
    } else {
        // Make sure A-Z was actually pressed
        if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keycode <= 90) {
            makeGuess(event.key.toLowerCase());
            updateDisplay();
            checkWin();
            checkLoss();
            console.log("eventListenerWorking16 makeGuess");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I added the debug console log. It seems that the script isn't picking up the keypress at all. Would it be the problem with the event listener? or would it have to do with something in the rest of the code, even though this is the only event listener i have.

Comment: As per my test, using that same piece of javascript code, the event is fired.

Please use https://jsfiddle.net/ to provide full example of what is happening in your code.

With current information i think the problem is not with the event listener and should be researched somewhere else in your context.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", myScript);
```